# Django: publishing and unpublishing posts

Tags: django, web-applications, django-admin

I have a basic Django blogging application with the fields such as textfield, datetime, imagefield, slug etc. I want to have a feature where I can publish and unpublish posts in the admin interface(with the help of checkbox). How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `BooleanField` that describes whether or not the post is published, and check the value of this field in your views.

Comment: It's propper way but you have to remember about two things:  
1. Add to your default manager filter(published=True). In many projects we got confused because unpublished data has been visible to the user somewhere (every developer forgets about that at least once in his career). Of course keeping model fat and view slim is good idea.  
2. Create an index like ('id', 'published') even if you have hardly anywhere unpublished items. It slows saves a little but can save you optimizations in future.